# Finding largest palindrome of a multiplication of 2 3 digits numbers limitation

Tags: python, windows, memory

Why does the following code stop at the palindrome of value: **580085** while the correct answer for the question is **906609** result of this multiplication: 993*913

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

    # Reverse algorithm
    def flipNumber( number ):
        nmbList     = list(str(number))

        i           = len( nmbList )
        reverseList = list()

        # reverse the list
        for x in nmbList:
            reverseList.append( nmbList[i-1] )
            i -= 1

        # join list items to one number & cast it to integer
        return int(''.join(reverseList))


    # Figure out if numbers are palindrome
    def isPalindrome( number ):
        return number == flipNumber( number )

    def multiplyRun(  ):
        for i in range( 100, 999 ):
            for y in range( 100, 999 ):
                if isPalindrome( i * y ):
                    maxPalind = i * y

        return maxPalind

    # simple tests
    # print( flipNumber( 90819 ) )
    # print( isPalindrum( 9009, 9009 ) )
    # print( isPalindrum( 9109, 9009 ) )
    # print( isPalindrum( 9009, 9019 ) )
    # print( isPalindrum( 9019, 9019 ) )
    # print( isPalindrum( 9119, 9119 ) )

    print(multiplyRun(  ))
```

If I change the second 100 to 600 (or higher) in the second for loop, I get the correct result. It's mind boggling really, as these nested loops should go over all the ranges... What am I doing wrong!? (might be something really stupid that I'm not seeing..)

Comment: def is_palindrome(n): return str(n) == str(n)[::-1] # is shorter

Comment: I think the proper term is [palindrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome).

Comment: Fixed :) sorry didn't review the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't verifying that you have a larger palindrum.

580085 is 995 * 583. So if you start at 600 you won't find this, but it is lower than the ideal solution, with a component higher than the real solution.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand why it should stop at 995 while the limit is 999, plus there are no breaking statements for the loops so why should it stop anyway?!

Comment: It shouldn't, if you start at 600 then you won't find 580085. You need to actually compare the palindromes to see which is larger. You are just assuming that the latest palindrome is larger.

Comment: isn't it true that if (xyz > abc & wst > efg) then (xyz * wst > abc * efg)? So comparison of larger palindrum is practically useless right? the code is simply throwing out 580085 and not continuing till the end!

Comment: @Link-: BTW `wst < efg` is why your assumption was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better way to find a palindrome:

```
def ispal(n): 
    return str(n)==str(n)[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) still new to python, this comes in handy

Comment: what does a "::" mean in python ? Couldn't find documentation!

Comment: @littlecegian: It is called an [extended slice](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html). The slice of `[::-1]` reverses an object that supports extended slices. `'123'[::-1]` reversed the string to produce `'321'`

Answer (score 2):

As Guvante said, you are looking at whether or not the two factors (995 and 583) are larger, not whether or not the final palindrome is larger.

the correct code is:

```
def multiplyRun(  ):
    for i in range( 100, 999 ):
        for y in range( 100, 999 ):
            if isPalindrome( i * y ):
                if i * y > maxPalind:
                    maxPalind = i * y

    return maxPalind
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a solution whithout brute force.

```
public long solveBestSolution(int nbChiffre) 
{
long chiffreMax = (long)Math.pow(10, nbChiffre);    
// Tip 1 : 111 * 111 is a palindrome
long chiffreMin = 1111111111111111111L % chiffreMax;
long max = chiffreMin * chiffreMin -1;

    // Tip2 : Take j >= i
    for (long i = chiffreMax - 1 ; i >= chiffreMin; i--) {
        for (long j = chiffreMax - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            long res = j * i;
            if(res > max)
            {
                if(this.checkPalindrome(res))
                {
                    max = res;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Tip 3
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```